# I have a string and it contain some integer and i want to subtract that integers

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, function, data-structures

```
userin=input("enter a question")
```

**SAMPLE Question/userin**

I have 10 pc and I gave 3 pc to my friend how many pc I left?

**What I want to do** = find integers from user given string and subtract integers 
**RESULT**
**10-3 = 7**

I Need answer in simplest way possible .Its a high school(12 grade) project.
I tried this

```
import re
ab=input("enter    ")
# \d is equivalent to [0-9].
p = re.compile('\d')
pr=p.findall(ab)
for i in pr:
    print(i, end="")
```

suggest me other best possible code to do same task.
i want to subtract it also

Comment: I don't get it? Can you show the exact input you want and output.

Comment: input is given by user and input can be anything(string + int)

Answer (score 3):

First, you do not want individual digits, but numbers that can be composed or more than one, so you regex should be `'\\d+'` (do not forget that a string *eats* backslashes) of `r'\d+'`:

```
ab=input("enter    ")
# \d is equivalent to [0-9].
p = re.compile(r'\d+')
pr = p.findall(ab)
if len(pr) == 2:
    print(int(pr[0]) - int(pr[1]))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can solve it without using regex too. Strings have built-in `isdigit()` method which will help you here:

```
userin=input("enter a question")

digits = [int(each) for each in userin.split() if each.isdigit()]
# -> [10, 3]

result = digits[0] - digits[1]
# -> 7
```